Where is my memory leaked?
I'm running Percona MySQL 8.0.36-28 on Kubernetes (GKE) and I am suffering of a constant memory leak I am not able to identify.
MySQL reports the memory usage is 1.8G, while when I check the memory usage by the process is nearly 2G (the limit of the Pod).

mysql> select * from sys.x$memory_global_total;
+-----------------+
| total_allocated |
+-----------------+
|      1821829040 |
+-----------------+

And when checking the code areas
| code_area                 | current_alloc |
+---------------------------+---------------+
| memory/innodb             | 1.37 GiB      |
| memory/performance_schema | 269.77 MiB    |
| memory/sql                | 53.75 MiB     |
| memory/mysys              | 9.35 MiB      |
| memory/temptable          | 1.00 MiB      |
| memory/mysqld_openssl     | 417.87 KiB    |
| memory/mysqlx             | 3.26 KiB      |
| memory/myisam             |  728 bytes    |
| memory/csv                |  120 bytes    |
| memory/blackhole          |  120 bytes    |
| memory/vio                |   80 bytes    |
+---------------------------+---------------+

I can see the total memory is ~1.6GB , however my pod memory usage constantly grows until it's limit 2GB.
---------------- ------- ------- -------
total kB         6241796 2082968 2046000

I can confirm this also with Kubernetes metrics

If I inspect pmap over the time, I can see it is some anon memory allocation but I cannot relate this to anything in MySQL.
Output from MySQLTuner
 >>  MySQLTuner 2.5.2
     * Jean-Marie Renouard <jmrenouard@gmail.com>
     * Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[--] Performing tests on 127.0.0.1:3306
[OK] Logged in using credentials passed on the command line
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM -ndbcluster -ndbinfo +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 13.5G (Tables: 789)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 8.0.36-28

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] log_error is set to stderr, but this script can't read stderr

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

(...)

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] NO SECURITY CVE FOUND FOR YOUR VERSION

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 8h 2m 18s (1M q [68.777 qps], 36K conn, TX: 1008M, RX: 838M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 82% / 18%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 32.0G. <--- This is not correctly reported because MySQLTunner seems not to detect the cgroup limit, which is 2G, 32G is the VM Node where this is running.
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 1.8G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 1.3G global + 1.9M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] Performance_schema Max memory usage: 269M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 1.6G (5.08% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 1.8G (5.68% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (708/1M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 31% (48/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00% (1/36725)
[--] Query cache has been removed since MySQL 8.0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (776 temp sorts / 103K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 362
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 1% (42 on disk / 2K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 79% (7K created / 36K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 99% (4M hits / 4M requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache (2000) is greater than number of tables (1128)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (1/1M)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (9 immediate / 9 locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance_schema is activated.
[--] Memory used by Performance_schema: 269.8M
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] General MyIsam metrics:
[--]  +-- Total MyISAM Tables  : 0
[--]  +-- Total MyISAM indexes : 0B
[--]  +-- KB Size :8.0M
[--]  +-- KB Used Size :1.5M
[--]  +-- KB used :18.2%
[--]  +-- Read KB hit rate: 0% (0 cached / 0 reads)
[--]  +-- Write KB hit rate: 0% (0 cached / 0 writes)
[--] No MyISAM table(s) detected ....

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB Buffer Pool size ( 1.0G ) under limit for 64 bits architecture: (17179869184.0G )
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 1.0G / 13.5G
[!!] Ratio Buffer Pool allocated / Buffer Pool Size: 77.55%
[!!] Ratio InnoDB redo log capacity / InnoDB Buffer pool size (9.375%): 256.0M / 1.0G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 8 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.99% (1644265771 hits / 1644483751 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 92.21% (5230510 hits / 5672273 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 441763 writes)

(All disabled metrics)

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
(n/a no replication)

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours: recommendations may be inaccurate
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size
    Be careful, increasing innodb_redo_log_capacity means higher crash recovery mean time
Variables to adjust:
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 13.5G) if possible.
    innodb_redo_log_capacity should be (=256M) if possible, so InnoDB Redo log Capacity equals 25% of buffer pool size.

Output from SHOW Global Status
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST;
+-------+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+------------------------+------------------+----------+-----------+---------------+
| Id    | User            | Host      | db   | Command | Time  | State                  | Info             | Time_ms  | Rows_sent | Rows_examined |
+-------+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+------------------------+------------------+----------+-----------+---------------+
|     5 | event_scheduler | localhost | NULL | Daemon  | 29289 | Waiting on empty queue | NULL             | 29288894 |         0 |             0 |
| 37203 | root            | localhost | NULL | Query   |     0 | init                   | SHOW PROCESSLIST |        0 |         0 |             0 |
+-------+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+-------+------------------------+------------------+----------+-----------+---------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

SHOW GLOBAL STATUS

Hi @nbk, I am not understanding how that could be affecting, could you give me an example?
